# Visual Studio for specific purpose

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We have following requirements for a ASP.Net Web Form and MVC projects.

1. Connect to TFS Server
2. Create class Diagram and Sequence Diagram from code
3. Unit Testing of classes
4. Code coverage result
5. Installer projects for deployment

No more fancy stuffs are needed.

I have referred the matrix for [Capabilities comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare). But I am not able to figure out which is the most economic version that will meet these requirmenets.

Which is the most economic edition of **Visual Studio 2012** that will meet these specific requirements?